# Fill missing value based on value from another column in the same row

Tags: python, pandas

I have a DataFrame looks like this

```
ColA | ColB | ColC | ColD |
-----|------|------|------|
100  |   A  |  X1  |  NaN |
200  |   B  |  X2  |  AAA |
300  |   C  |  X3  |  NaN |
```

I want to fill the missing value on **ColD** based on value on **ColA**. The result I need is like:

```
if value in ColA = 100 then value in ColD = "BBB"
if value in ColA = 300 then value in ColD = "CCC"

ColA | ColB | ColC | ColD |
-----|------|------|------|
100  |   A  |  X1  |  BBB |
200  |   B  |  X2  |  AAA |
300  |   C  |  X3  |  CCC |
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [`combine_first`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.combine_first.html) or [`fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.fillna.html):

```
df.ColD = df.ColD.combine_first(df.ColA)
print (df)
   ColA ColB ColC ColD
0   100    A   X1  100
1   200    B   X2  AAA
2   300    C   X3  300
```

Or:

```
df.ColD = df.ColD.fillna(df.ColA)
print (df)
   ColA ColB ColC ColD
0   100    A   X1  100
1   200    B   X2  AAA
2   300    C   X3  300
```

EDIT: First use [`map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.map.html) for `Series` `s` and then `combine_first` or `fillna` by this `Series`:

```
d = {100: "BBB", 300:'CCC'}
s = df.ColA.map(d)
print (s)
0    BBB
1    NaN
2    CCC
Name: ColA, dtype: object

df.ColD = df.ColD.combine_first(s)
print (df)
   ColA ColB ColC ColD
0   100    A   X1  BBB
1   200    B   X2  AAA
2   300    C   X3  CCC
```

---

It replace only `NaN`:

```
print (df)
   ColA ColB ColC ColD
0   100    A   X1  EEE <- changed value to EEE
1   200    B   X2  AAA
2   300    C   X3  NaN

d = {100: "BBB", 300:'CCC'}
s = df.ColA.map(d)
df.ColD = df.ColD.combine_first(s)
print (df)
   ColA ColB ColC ColD
0   100    A   X1  EEE
1   200    B   X2  AAA
2   300    C   X3  CCC
```

Comment: OP wants ```ColA```value mapped/transformed and the result inserted into ```ColD```.

Comment: Thanks @jezrael for a very quick reply! My question was not clear actually. I 've updated my question with my expected result. Please have a look again. :)

Comment: Hi @jezrael, I tried your code on the same data, why does the last `combine_first` (after `map`) not work on me?

Comment: There can be problem different dtypes, then get no match. Need same. Check it by df.dtypes, if get object it it obviously string.

Answer (score 1):

Define a mapping function:

```
def my_map_func(x):
    return "BBB" if x==100 else "CCC"
```

Right now, df looks like:

```
ColA | ColB | ColC | ColD
-----|------|------|-----
100  |    A |   X1 |  NaN
200  |    B |   X2 |  AAA
300  |    C |   X3 |  NaN
```

Select the rows that have NaN, and fill it with mapped value obtained from column ColA

```
df.ix[df.ColD.isnull(), 'ColD'] = df.ix[df.ColD.isnull(), 'ColA'].apply(my_map_func)
```

Here, we are basically selecting only those rows for which *ColD* is NaN by indexing based on a boolean series and selecting the column, *ColA* we are interested in. In simple language, *df.ix[selected_rows, selected_columns]*.

Now, dataframe df looks like:

```
ColA | ColB | ColC | ColD
-----|------|------|-----
100  |    A |   X1 |  BBB
200  |    B |   X2 |  AAA
300  |    C |   X3 |  CCC
```